# Bash : sort command do not treat dots

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have an array :

```
a=("toto.blabla" "toto.dlabla" "totodlabla")
```

then I do :

```
IFS=$'\n'; echo "${a[*]}" | sort -d; unset IFS
```

but the result is :

```
toto.blabla
totodlabla
toto.dlabla
```

instead of :

```
toto.blabla
toto.dlabla
totodlabla
```

Why sort command do not treat dots ?

Best regards,

Olivier

Comment: What do you mean by "do not treat dots"? `.` has a lower character code than letters, so it sorts ahead of them.

Comment: And `-d` is the option to "consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters"

Comment: BTW, you should not `unset IFS`, you should set it back to the normal default.

Comment: Or use `printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"` and not touch `IFS`

Comment: Ok thank you for the explaination, is there a way to sort like i want it to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When sorting, your current locale is influencing the order. If you want locale independent order, use the C locale:

```
IFS=$'\n'; echo "${a[*]}" | LC_ALL=C sort -d; unset IFS
```

Setting `LC_COLLATE` should be enough, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it works :-)

With LC_ALL=C but not with LC_COLLATE=C